# Unable to include and exclude fields of query via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some schema and making query as following :

```
mongoose.model('mymodel').find({}, 'one -two -__v', function(err,docs){});
```

I want documents should only return the field 'one'. Always ignore the fields 'two' and rest all.
Then i get the following error :

```
You cannot currently mix including and excluding fields. Contact us if this is an issue.
```

I am generating the field string dynamically to include or exclude the fields required.

How to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with mongoose. The "limitation" exists within mongo itself.

From the [collection.find documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

> A projection cannot contain both include and exclude specifications, except for the exclusion of the `_id` field. In projections that explicitly include fields, the `_id` field is the only field that you can explicitly exclude.

---

You either include, **or** exclude, you can't do both, (with the exception of `_id`)

Select only `_id` and `one`

```
'one'
```

Select all fields except for `two`

```
'-two'
```

**Exception:** Select only `one` *without* `_id`

```
'one -_id'
```

Comment: Was just about to mention this was a MongoDB issue but that is added. Still worth mentioning that the "version" field is mongoose specific so therefore cannot be excluded in this way. But you can be specific about the fields using aggregate.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Feel free to edit my answer if you'd like.

Comment: I don't like to jump in on correct answers, just leaving a note. The point was to look at the [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator for the aggregation pipeline. It is more specific than the projection in `.find()`. Used with the $match operator you end up with a better version of `.find()`. Especially in [new releases](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/#aggregation-enhancements) where `.aggregate()` returns a cursor.